# how can i edit text in the UI within a script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I wanted to edit the text in the UI to display a health value and score. but I don't know how I would go about creating code to edit the piece of text in the first place

Comment: What have you tried?  Its hard to help when you have no code to show.

Answer (score 2):

To edit the Text component in Unity you need to do this:
Create a public Text field. In a function, for example Start (), it assigns a string to the Text component. Go to the inspector to assign the Text component to the public field.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ChangeText : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text text;

    void Start()
    {
        text.text = “example text”;
    }
}
```

See [the documentation here.](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Text-text.html)

if you think my answer helped you, you can mark it as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). I would very much appreciate it :)